# i want to create multiple column into two column layout without using flex and grid

Tags: html, css, laravel, dompdf

I need to create multiple columns into two column layout without using flex and grid. because im using dompdf plugin in laravel. dompdf doesn't support grid and flex. because it doesn't support css v3.Please give a layout design in css2(without flex and grid).I don't prefer table format, because the two column layout may or may not have the same height. thats why it has to resize the height and the empty space occupied by the next div.Thanks. [image]

Comment: u can use bootrap.

Comment: You can stretch the items if you use flex or grid so that the items appear same height

Comment: dompdf doesn't support bootstrap

Comment: streching a div not useful !. problem is i can't make two column row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title></title>
</head>
<style type="text/css">
    *{
        outline: none;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    .area{
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
    }
    .container{
        max-width: 260px;
        padding-top: 1rem;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    .box{
        display: inline-block;
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        background: lightgreen;
    }
</style>
<body>
    <div class="area">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="box">1</div>
            <div class="box">2</div>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="box">3</div>
            <div class="box">4</div>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="box">5</div>
            <div class="box">6</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this using laravel

```html
<table class="table" style="width:100%">
        @foreach ($isi as $data)
        @if ($loop->iteration % 2 == 1)
            <tr>
        @endif
            <td align="center">
                 <p align="center">image 1</p>
                </td>
                @if ($loop->iteration % 2 == 0)
            </tr>
                @endif
            @endforeach
      </table>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).